# Selected value missed if use model in DropDownListFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble this DropDownListFor()

I have test controller:

```
model.COUNTRYNAME = "Swizerland";
        ViewBag.Selecter = new SelectList(new[]  
        { 
            new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" }, 
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Swizerland", Value = "Swizerland", Selected =true}, 
             new SelectListItem { Text = "Russia", Value = "Russia" }, 

        }, "Text", "Value", model.COUNTRYNAME);
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.COUNTRYNAME , (SelectList)ViewBag.Selecter)
```

The DropDownListFor does not have select value, it always select first value.

What is wrong?

If i use DropDownList

```
@Html.DropDownList("COUNTRYNAME" , (SelectList)ViewBag.Selecter)
```

It also don't work.

But if I use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("AAAAAAA" , (SelectList)ViewBag.Selecter)
```

It's work fine and select 2nd value! What happens? I don't understand.

Thanks

Comment: Its "Switzerland" not "Swizeland".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
model.COUNTRYNAME = "Swizeland";
ViewBag.Selecter = new[]  
{ 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Swizeland", Value = "Swizeland" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Russia", Value = "Russia" }, 
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.COUNTRYNAME, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Selecter
)
```

but a better way is to use a view model:

```
model.SelectedCountry = "Swizeland";
model.Countries = new[]  
{ 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Swizeland", Value = "Swizeland" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Russia", Value = "Russia" }, 
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, Model.Countries)
```

Comment: This works. I have tested it. If it doesn't work for you this means that you have some other code. In this case please provide a full example (controller, action, view) allowing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Many Thanks for help.I tried use 1st case, it doesn't work. But I try use the "model" and it works! It's very strange. I cann't use the Entity in "model"? I forced convert Entity to Adapter and back?

Comment: I can't say if you are doing something wrong without knowing what you are doing actually by showing your code allowing me to reproduce the problem.